# Why can't ECHO be disabled (disable_functions) in PHP-FPM pools or php.ini?

Tags: configuration, php

You will find that `echo` can't be disabled. It's ignored and it and does not throw any error either when you restart the `php-fpm` service. There's probably no real reason that would lead you to disabling `echo` but extra knowledge is always welcome.

A test config can be:

```
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = echo,exec,shell_exec,phpinfo
```

The other functions being "control" functions, to ensure the pool is being read properly. You will find that `echo` simply is ignored but the other functions are disabled correctly.

Link **https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php** says

> Only internal functions can be disabled using this directive.
> User-defined functions are unaffected.

So why is `echo` not affected? Is it not an internal function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason ECHO is not affected is because ECHO is not a function.

Info found in **https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php**

> echo is not a function but a language construct. Its arguments are a
> list of expressions following the echo keyword, separated by commas,
> and not delimited by parentheses. Unlike some other language
> constructs, echo does not have any return value, so it cannot be used
> in the context of an expression.

Paradoxically the ECHO information is found in the "String Functions" section in the PHP manual and even the link to the page says as seen above "/manual/en/**function.echo**.php"